# Is there any way to tell when a user's password was changed?

Tags: 7, users, log-messages

A user tried to log on today and discovered that his password had mysteriously been changed. All I can assume is that he left his computer unattended and someone changed it.

Is there any way to tell *when* this happened, so as to narrow down who might have done it? I suspect the answer is "no" - I don't see a watchdog entry, and in `/var/log/mysql` all there is is an error log, not a log of queries.

Is there another place where DB queries might be logged or is there somewhere else in Drupal I could check?

Comment: Is this for Drupal 7 or 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to tell from the database it-self when user changed his password.

The user password in Drupal 7 is stored in [`users` table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.install/function/user_schema/7.x) with the following columns of interest:

- `pass` - User's password (hashed).
- `access` - Timestamp for previous time user accessed the site.
- `login` - Column which tells you timestamp for user's last login.

However there are few workarounds:

- If you've got logging enabled (*dblog* or *syslog*), Drupal logs when particular user has logged in. This should point you to the IP address (whether it's different as usual).
- On live environments, periodical backups of database should be a must. Depending how often you do the backups, compare different dumps focusing on particular user and his password, for example:

  ```
  gzcat db-dump-2017*.sql.gz | grep -w users | grep -w pass | grep specific_user
  ```

  <sup>Note: Above command attempts to stream compressed dump of database in order to find value of `pass` column from `users` table for the given user.</sup>

  Then check which database dump has the new changed password. From there you can check the logs (e.g. from `watchdog` table) for this user. Especially check IP addresses, requested URLs and authorization attempts (whether successful or failures).